# AvalonEdit - XMLFolding -> Ignore the first line

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, avalonedit

Would it be possible to ignore the first line when trying to update the foldings?

```
Ignore this line
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</Ffrom>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Right now this is not recognized as a valid XMLDocument and the reader will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following will skip first line

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            reader.ReadLine(); // skip first line

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for but good enough, thanks. In order for it to work with avalon edit you will have to implement your custom UpdateFoldings and CreateNewFoldings